Loaded Addresses
Calling getTransaction method we potentially could have loaded Addresses
whats the point in this if we still need to fetch address table lookup?

Could you elaborate what you mean? getTransactions is a client side rpc call whereas LUTs are usually mostly relevant inside programs.
